# Hide sidebar if post_type is in array

Tags: array

I would like to hide the sidebar on certain post types. I can hide it on **one** post type by using:

```
if ('example' != get_post_type()) {
```

How could I use the above with an array?

```
$hide_sidebar = array('example1', 'example2', 'example3'); //hide sidebar on these post types

if( /*post type is not in $hide_sidebar*/ ){
  get_sidebar();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more php, but you can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Just check if the current post type is in array in `$hide_sidebar`.

You can do the following

```
$hide_sidebar = array('example1', 'example2', 'example3'); //hide sidebar on these post types
if ( in_array( get_post_type(), $hide_sidebar ) ) {
    // Do something if the post type is in array
}
```

or the negative

```
$hide_sidebar = array('example1', 'example2', 'example3'); //hide sidebar on these post types
if ( !in_array( get_post_type(), $hide_sidebar ) ) {
    // Do something if the post type is not in array
}
```

Comment: Mr. Goosen strikes again!:) Ha ha thank you, works perfectly. You're right, this is more of a PHP question. Should I remove it or leave it up for others anyway?

Comment: You can just leave it for future reference :-). Glad it worked for you. Enjoy